# How do make the Fluence service_id fixed on each deployment?

Tags: fluence

I`m running my own Fluence service and deploy to the node using the command below

```
aqua remote deploy_service \
--addr multiaddr  \
--config-path configs/service_config.json \
--service service_name \
--sk your_secret_key
```

The deployment is successful with the command above, and resulting a new service_id

```
"service_id": "d97c8343-bd97-4adc-a14f-3bdc46fbe15a"
```

The deployed service is always have **new service _id**, is there a way to make the ID fixed or unchangeable on each deployment?

Answer (score 0):

no, that's the only way to differentiate between multiple instantiations but you can use registry, ttps://github.com/fluencelabs/registry, a distributed kv store to map (potentially rotating) service id(s) to a (permanent) key you can use in your Aqua app.